# find the next input field which is in next div-jquery

Tags: jquery

I am getting the last element of the form which has got value, now i want to find the  id of next input element which is in next div...

```
 var elem1 =$(':text[name^=distanceSlab][value!=""]').last(); 
 var nextElemId = // find the id of next input element which is in next div
```

the corresponding html code is

```
 <div id ="divid4">
  <input type="text"  id ="slab4" value ="1"/> // this is the last elemnt which has value
 </div>

 <div id ="div1d5">
      <input type="text"  id ="slab5" value =""/> // need to find the id of this element
 </id>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming that you're starting from the `input` that you've already identified, then:

```
$(this).closest('div').next('div').find('input:text').attr('id');
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7BUBc/).

Or:

```
var thisIndex = $(this).index('input:text');

var next = thisIndex + 1;

var nextElemId = $('input:text').eq(next).attr('id');
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7BUBc/1/).

I'd probably put those into a `blur()`, or similar, event.